# Subclassing pd.DataFrame class results in `object has no attribute '_data'` when trying to display the data

Tags: python, pandas, subclass

I'm trying to create a (very simple) pandas subclass, likeso:

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2], 'B': [2, 3], 'C': [4, 5]})

class TestFrame(pd.DataFrame):
    # See https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/development/extending.html#extending-extension-types
    _metadata = pd.DataFrame._metadata + ["addnl"]

    @property
    def _constructor(self):
        return TestFrame

    @property
    def _constructor_sliced(self):
        return pd.Series

    @classmethod
    def plus_one(
        cls,
        df,
    ):
        tf = super().__new__(cls, df)
        tf.addnl = 1
        return tf

t1 = TestFrame.plus_one(data)
```

This proceeds without error, except that trying to view t1 gives me `AttributeError: 'TestFrame' object has no attribute '_data'`.

I think this is because I am calling `DataFrame.__new__` instead of `__init__`, because it gives the same error for this:

```
object.__new__(pd.DataFrame, {'A': [1, 2], 'B': [2, 3], 'C': [4, 5]})
```

However, I can't then find a way to define the constructor. This is made more problematic by the fact that the pandas subclassing infrastructure doesn't yet (as far as I can tell) let you define an `__init__` with new attributes.

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: @Stephen Rauch I'm calling DataFrame.__new__ in the plus_one method.

Comment: Why are you doing `__new__`?

Comment: @StephenRauch I'm trying to create a constructor for the df subclass. Since this code is not working, if you have an alternative approach then obviously don't keep it to yourself. Sorry - misread your earlier comment, I thought you said 'where'.

Comment: Can you explain what the subclass is trying to achieve? There is likely an issue with how you're initialising `plus_one`.

Comment: @cs95 - this is just an example, obviously, but the real-life one is only slightly more complex - adding a couple of methods and a couple of attributes to pd.DataFrame.

Comment: Change the first line in the method to `tf = TestFrame(df.to_numpy(), columns=df.columns)` and `print(t1)` should work. Although I'm still not clear on the goal here. Is this supposed to add 1 to all values from df?

Comment: @cs95 - No, it's not meant to add one, just an example of adding an additional attribute. Your suggestion does work (as does `tf = TestFrame(df)`), which is great, but I had in mind that this was not an ideal solution since it's hard-wiring in a reference to the class (rather than using `super()`).

Comment: I don't think `super()` is the right move here. Nothing wrong with hardcoding a reference to the class, but you can use `tf = cls(df)` if you want to avoid that, I suppose

Comment: @cs95 - I think that I was thinking that I needed to use super(), because my subclass had overriden pd.DataFrame's __new__ or __init__. But since I haven't overriden either, the super() reference is not needed. Anyway thanks for this, I had been bashing on my head against it for at least an hour. Do you want to propose this as a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is that the line `tf = super().__new__(cls, df)` does not make sense. You are not overriding `DataFrame.__init__` or `__new__` so you don't have to use `super()` to call them.

If the idea is to instantiate a frame of type `TestFrame`, you can use `tf = cls(df)`.

```
@classmethod
def plus_one(cls, df):
    tf = cls(df)
    tf.addnl = 1

    return tf
```